# Spool to CSV with SQL*Plus and then convert the CSV to PDF

Tags: excel, bash, pdf, csv, rhel

I have a SQL that spools some results to a CSV file which then gets e-mailed out to customers. The way that Microsoft Excel (usually the end users default application for opening CSV files) is slightly confusing for some end users in that the columns usually need to be made larger (otherwise #'s are shown etc.) before it can be printed.

Is it possible to spool straight to a PDF file, or to convert the CSV to an easier to read PDF before e-mailing out?

I searched online for a command-line tool to convert a CSV to a PDF but come up blank. This is generated on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server without a RHN subscription so something with a lot of dependencies would be a nightmare to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several txt2pdf programs both free and proprietary for different platforms.
A google search for **txt2pdf** gives an enourmous amount of hits.
What is left is converting csv to text (which is very easy because csv *is* text)

You may want to write (or ask for) a simple script that changes the csv to your liking before it gets converted to pdf.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching for 'CSV to PDF' which didn't bring up many results when in fact I should have been searching for 'TXT to PDF' as you've said!

Answer (score 0):

Adding the reply given by thom, you can actually(if possible) edit the SQL file itself to spew out a txt file with required delimiters and spaces, therby eliminating the need for converting csv to txt. Like I have a sql file which prints data present in a row in each line of the text file with comma separated column values and each record(or tuple) is separated by a line of '|'. You can check each property I have set and what it stands for, thereby you can print out something according to your needs

```
SET SPACE 0
SET LINESIZE 500
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET RECSEP each
SET RECSEPCHAR |
SPOOL spool_out.txt
select col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4 from table;
SPOOL OFF
exit
/
```